# How can i acccess funds that i sent to an OP address even though the safe was only created on ARB

Tags: blockchain, gnosis-safe, recovery

Ive created a arb safe but falsely sent op funds there. how can i retrieve the assets and send them to the ARB network / to a different wallet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to deploy a safe with the same address on Optimism. It's not always possible, it depends on how it was created. We can help if you provide the safe address.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this guide, sometimes it's possible to recover funds: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/5267779-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover